# How do I copy the rigidbody properties of an object and paste them on an other one? [Blender 2.93]

Tags: shortcut

For example I have a sphere that I just spawned and cube with several settings.

The cube has the "Rigid body" physics with numerous parameters (Type:Active, Mass:20kg, Friction:1.00, etc.)

I want to be able to copy these settings from the Cube and paste them on an other shape I just spawned. For example a UV Sphere.

How do I do that?

[image: not sure if it's really helpful but here's the scene]

Answer (score 3):

If you first select the UV sphere, then Shift-click on the cube so that both are selected and the cube is the active object, you can choose *Object* > *Rigid Body* > *Copy from Active*. This way the settings are transferred.

This works if the sphere is not yet a *Rigid Body* as well as when it already is one but has different settings. You can also select multiple objects at once to which you want to copy the cube's settings.

[image: rigid body copy settings]